# GPIO not sending LOW when called

Tags: python, multithreading, gpio

So I am updating the global status and trying to call the GPIO high and low accordingly.
It works the first time that to only when I send HIGH, and doesn't work when I try to send LOW. Even HIGH works only the first time. Is GPIO not compatible with threads or what is going on.

Function:

```
from shared_memory_dict import SharedMemoryDict
global_status = SharedMemoryDict(name='tokens', size=1024)

from threading import Thread

lock = threading.Lock()
def update_gpio():
    while True:
        global global_status
        with lock:
            print(global_status)
    #global gpio_l1,gpio_l2,gpio_l3
            if global_status['kitchen_light1'] == 1:
                print("1")
                gpio.output(26, gpio.HIGH)
            else:
                gpio.output(26, gpio.LOW)
                print("2")
            if global_status['bedroom1_light1'] == 1:
                gpio.output(20, gpio.HIGH)
                print("3")
            else:
                gpio.output(20, gpio.LOW)
                print("4")
            if global_status['bedroom2_light1'] == 1:
                gpio.output(21, gpio.HIGH)
                print("5")
            else:
                gpio.output(21, gpio.LOW)
                print("6")
        time.sleep(2)

t = Thread(target=update_gpio)
t.start()
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you want `update_gpio()` to continually run in a separate thread? The `global_status` isn't going to change by itself. Some other thread or process must change it. Why can't that other process/thread also change the status of the appropriate GPIO pin at the same time?

Comment: It is a long program and i only put in the gpio part. So basically i have 2 processes changing the global_status one is the tkinter GUI, and another is a flask server. To be precise the problem occurs when the global_status is changed via Flask server.

Answer (score 1):

The `GPIO` pins is not initialized in the proper way, it need to be setup before  you use it, also you have to import the `RPI.GPIO` library, below is the modified version

```
import time
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from shared_memory_dict import SharedMemoryDict

global_status = SharedMemoryDict(name='tokens', size=1024)

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(26, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(20, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(21, gpio.OUT)

lock = threading.Lock()

def update_gpio():
    while True:
        global global_status
        with lock:
            print(global_status)
            if global_status['kitchen_light1'] == 1:
                print("1")
                gpio.output(26, gpio.HIGH)
            else:
                gpio.output(26, gpio.LOW)
                print("2")
            if global_status['bedroom1_light1'] == 1:
                gpio.output(20, gpio.HIGH)
                print("3")
            else:
                gpio.output(20, gpio.LOW)
                print("4")
            if global_status['bedroom2_light1'] == 1:
                gpio.output(21, gpio.HIGH)
                print("5")
            else:
                gpio.output(21, gpio.LOW)
                print("6")
        time.sleep(2)

t = threading.Thread(target=update_gpio)
t.start()
```

Comment: I have initialized, and imported stuff, it was a long program and i only decided to share some of it.